# In HP QC 10 , how can I increase the font size of a field?

Tags: quality-center

Several of my team's QC users have complained about the text in description & comments fields being too small to read. Is there a way to increase the font size? Is there a way to change the font?

Comment: Part of me thinks if there isn't an official setting, you might be able to track down the css file with a little sleuthing!

Answer (score 1):

I have found this answer, May be it will help you:

You can enlarge the text in QC for easier viewing by doing this:

1. Click with the mouse in the text window you want to enlarge
2. Click left mouse button and keep it pressed down
3. Scroll up with the scroll wheel of the mouse (scroll down to reduce the font size)
4. Release scroll wheel and left mouse button.

Comment: That may work in some windows, but not everywhere. I just upgraded to QC12 today, I still do not know how to adjust the fonts, but the default fonts are larger.

Answer (score 1):

Single click in the field (eg Input Conditions).
Then right-click to show a menu - and select Zoom In.

This amount of zoom will then be used every time you click into a field.

Comment: While this worked for me, once the text field loses focus it returns to the original small font

Answer (score 0):

Click with the mouse in the text window you want to enlarge
On the keyboard select  + <+> to enlarge font size
Select  + <-> to decrease font size